# In Melty Blood, is Shiki Nanaya the master or servant of White Len?

Tags: melty-blood

I'm really confused as to whether Shiki Nanaya is the master or servant of White Len. At first, he seems to act as a Familiar created by White Len, but then he says that he'll be a good master to White Len. There's also the fact that he only came into physical existence outside TATARI because of White Len, since every other appearance outside *Melty Blood* he has been a persona of Shiki.

So, is he White Len's master—like how Shiki is Len's Master—or are the roles reversed, and she is the master keeping his physical existence in the world (as Familiars can only be in the world if supplied with *prana* from their master)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

White Len's contract with Nanaya (this is the supressed personality of Tohno Shiki, from *Tsukihime*) is a symbiotic (yet seemingly contradictory) one -- she maintains his existence with her TATARI powers, while he supplies her with the prana she needs to survive.

However, in the White Len ending in *Act Cadenza*, Nanaya clears states that he is in the "master" role:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i4O_rLYRESs#t=454s